# Load a local json file in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to load a JSON file in my app in JavaScript.

The json file is like this:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "item1": "text",
      "item2": "text",
      "item3": "text",
      "item4": "text"
    },
    {
      "item1": "text",
      "item2": "text",
      "item3": "text",
      "item4": "text"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I've searched, but I always find solutions using AJAX and PHP, but I don't (and I can't) use any PHP server. So I've looked from the side of jQuery and the `getJson()` function, but that's didn't work, the JavaScript `JSON.parse()` didn't work for my file.

So, do any of you know how to load a local file with JavaScript or any other API?

Comment: Can you post the code that didn't work and any error messages? `$.getJson()` should already parse the JSON, no need to call JSON.parse().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open a local file using javascript. The browser will not allow you, this is a security issue. (Save for using HTML5 FileAPI, but I don't think that is what you are asking)

However, you can place your .json files on a web server and load via a URL them using jquery.

```
$.getJSON("http://yourdomain.com/somefolder/test.json", function( data ) {
  //do something here with json data
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/